# Spiking AWS Lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda, throttling

When I create Lambda functions in AWS (For example, a resource not found error), the functions are triggering lambda in a recurring the same invocation errors and ending up in throttles.

Why does not Lambda stop at the first invocation error. Why does it keep trying for with the same error? I do use a ReservedConcurrentExecutions restriction to 1 to stop parallel processing.

Comment: Please re-read your question and see if you can clarify it.  It isn't clear what you are using to trigger these functions.

Comment: Found some related material with Dead Letter Queues where the function re-tries for a few attempts.